# Is it possible to use two objects: Force and Multiple in Cypress Test?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am using cypress test to check all the buttons in the page whether they can be clicked or not.

I have used this line of code:

```js
cy.get('button').click({ force: true }).should('have.attr', 'href')
```

and gives error

> CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your
>   subject contained 5 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to
>   serially click each element.

After that changed code with:

```js
cy.get('button').click({ multiple: true }).should('have.attr', 'href')
```

and got another error

> CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this
>   element is not visible:
>
> ...
>
> This element
>   ''
>   is not visible because it has CSS property: 'display: none'
>
> Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
>
> https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

Is there any way to use both object to solve the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work (I don't have a situation to test it when both needed, but it doesn't result in an error):

```js
cy.get('button')
  .click({ multiple: true, force: true })
  .should('have.attr', 'href')
```

Comment: Have same problem with another test, used above code and finally worked. Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion, dont use multiple true, you can give unique id or class or testid attribute to your buton and then target that element by id.By, this way you will never get this error. 

<button id="mybutton" data-test-id="custom-id-button">Send Email"</button>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way of doing it -

```
cy.get('button').each(($btn) => {
        if ($btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
            // logic to deal with disabled button
        }
        else {
            // click button or do whatever
            cy.wrap($btn).should('have.attr', 'href').click();
        }
    })
```

each will help you loop through every button, whatever may be the count. This allows you to not worry about force clicking an element (button in this case).